How to combine a list of dictionaries within JSON?
I have an end-point returning this JSON structure:
dataList = [{

    "item one" : 1234,
    "item two" : "5678",
    "item three" : "90",
    "item_list_one" : [ {
        "first_item_list_item_one" : 1,
        "first_item_list_item_two" : "def",
        "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc"
        
    },
    {
        "first_item_list_item_one" : 1,
        "first_item_list_item_two" : "def",
        "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc"
        
    },


],
    "item_list_two" : [{
        "second_item_list_item_four" : 2,
        "second_item_list_item_five" : "mno",
        "second_item_list_item_six" : "pqr"
    },
    {
        "item_list_item_seven" : 1,
        "item_list_item_eight" : "def",
        "item_list_item_nine" : "abc"
        
    },
]
}]

I would like to combine "item_list_one" and "item_list_two" within their parent.
This gets me inside of the JSON
for index in range(len(dataList)):
    for key, value in dataList[index].items():
        print(key,value)

But when I try to access "item_list_one" for example, it doesn't know what that is...
for index in range(len(dataList)):
    for key, value in dataList[index].items():
        for index in range(len(item_list_one)):
            for i in item_list_one.items():
                print(i)

I know we can combine dictionaries in Python by doing {dict_1 + dict_2) but I can't get to that stage for some reason.
I would like it to look like this:
dataList = [{

    "item one" : 1234,
    "item two" : "5678",
    "item three" : "90",
    "combined_list" : [ {
        {
        "first_item_list_item_one" : 1,
        "first_item_list_item_two" : "def",
        "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc"
        
    },
    {
        "first_item_list_item_one" : 2,
        "first_item_list_item_two" : "ghi",
        "first_item_list_item_three" : "pon"
        
    },
    {
        "second_item_list_item_one" : 4,
        "second_item_list_item_two" : "grf",
        "second_item_list_item_three" : "bfc"
        
    }, ...
]
}]


I've the answer ready. But before posting I want to confirm something. In the original dict, 'item_list_two' starts from "second_item_list_item_four", "second_item_list_item_five" & "second_item_list_item_six"  whereas in the output you've mentioned "second_item_list_item_one" , "second_item_list_item_two"  and "second_item_list_item_three". I assumed that you wanted to change the key's name. But their respective values are also 4, 'grf' and 'bfc' which are not there in the original list. Kindly clarify.

@SuramuthuR hi, thank you for asking. I added that last minute and didn't check to see if it matched. My apologies. I just want to combine item_list_one and item_list_two into one combined list within the parent

Check my answer now. If you want some thing else, I can modify accordingly.

You want to combine "item_list_one" and "item_list_two" within their parent and form a single list, for that you can iterate through each dictionary in dataList. Please look at the code below:
dataList = [{ "item one" : 1234, "item two" : "5678", "item three" : "90", "item_list_one" : [ { "first_item_list_item_one" : 1, "first_item_list_item_two" : "def", "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc" }, { "first_item_list_item_one" : 1, "first_item_list_item_two" : "def", "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc" }, ], "item_list_two" : [{ "second_item_list_item_four" : 2, "second_item_list_item_five" : "mno", "second_item_list_item_six" : "pqr" }, { "item_list_item_seven" : 1, "item_list_item_eight" : "def", "item_list_item_nine" : "abc" }, ] }]

for item in dataList:
    combined_list = item.get("item_list_one", []) + item.get("item_list_two", [])
    item["combined_list"] = combined_list
    del item["item_list_one"]
    del item["item_list_two"]

print(dataList)


# Make the list into dict
dataList = dataList[0]

# Create an empty dict
new = {}

# If the value of key-value of datalist is not a dict make it key-value of new
for k, v in dataList.items():
    if not isinstance(v, list):
        new[k] = v

# remove the key-value pairs from datalist if they are in new
for x in new.keys(): dataList.pop(x)

# Create a key 'combined_list' in new, the value being an empty list
new['combined_list'] = []

# Iterate thru datalist
for k,v in dataList.items():

    # Iterate thru value of datalist
    for x in v:
        
        # Append the value to the value of 'combined_list' in new
        new['combined_list'].append(x)
        
print(new)

Output:
{
    'item one': 1234, 
    'item two': '5678',
    'item three': '90',
    'combined_list': [
                        {
                            'first_item_list_item_one': 1, 
                            'first_item_list_item_two': 'def', 
                            'first_item_list_item_three': 'abc'
                        },
                        
                        {
                            'first_item_list_item_one': 1,
                            'first_item_list_item_two': 'def',
                            'first_item_list_item_three': 'abc'
                        }, 
                        {
                            'second_item_list_item_four': 2, 
                            'second_item_list_item_five': 'mno',
                            'second_item_list_item_six': 'pqr'
                        }, 
                        {
                            'item_list_item_seven': 1,
                            'item_list_item_eight': 'def',
                            'item_list_item_nine': 'abc'
                        }
                    ]
}


you can look at this code :
dataList = [{

    "item one" : 1234,
    "item two" : "5678",
    "item three" : "90",
    "item_list_one" : [ {
        "first_item_list_item_one" : 1,
        "first_item_list_item_two" : "def",
        "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc"
        
    },
    {
        "first_item_list_item_one" : 1,
        "first_item_list_item_two" : "def",
        "first_item_list_item_three" : "abc"
        
    },


],
    "item_list_two" : [{
        "second_item_list_item_four" : 2,
        "second_item_list_item_five" : "mno",
        "second_item_list_item_six" : "pqr"
    },
    {
        "item_list_item_seven" : 1,
        "item_list_item_eight" : "def",
        "item_list_item_nine" : "abc"
        
    },
]
}]





first_dict = dataList[0]
item_list_one = first_dict.pop("item_list_one")
item_list_two = first_dict.pop("item_list_two")
first_dict.update({"combined_list" : item_list_one + item_list_two})


print(first_dict)


Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.
